# BufferedReader reader saty empty because HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); can't execute help me please

Tags: java

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is
```

Comment: Your code isn't complete.  Do you get any errors?  What have you tried to understand the problem?

Comment: this is part but the program when arrives after HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); will stop

Answer (score 0):

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

```
    try
    {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8080/list.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println("Exception 1");
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is , "iso-8859-1"),20);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null)

            sb.append(line +"\n");
            result = sb.toString();
            is.close();
            System.out.println("----------------Here Is My Data-------------------");
            System.out.println(result);


    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception 2");
    }
this is code but buffered reader stay empty
```

Comment: Please amend your question rather than post this as an answer